# How do I avoid this spark issue when converting a DataFrame into a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to convert my spark DataFrame into a list of dictionaries.
`new_df = list(map(lambda row: row.asDict(), df_base.collect()))`

But when I run the above, I keep getting the following error.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 5 tasks (4.3 GiB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize 4.0 GiB.
```

How do I work around this? Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is use `df_base.toLocalIterator()` instead of collect().
But do you really need to load more then 4GB data into local python list?
Do you consider df_base.toPandas() or use spark to run all your code.

```
 new_df = list(map(lambda row: row.asDict(), df_base.toLocalIterator()))
```

Comment: Is it better to use Pandas? I have a lot of data.

Comment: It is better to process and filter data using spark as much as possible and load to local python only small subsets. After that Pandas is good choose for data local processing. Spark has some optimizations for it https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/arrow_pandas.html